# 404 error when trying to delete comments in GitHub pull requests using actions

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I have saved the output of:

```bash
gh pr view ${{ github.event.number }} --json comments > comments.json
```

to `comments.json`

I then want to iterate on the saved comments and conditionally delete some of them as follows, trying to adhere to [these](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-an-issue-comment) guidelines:

```yaml
      - name: delete comments
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          result-encoding: string
          script: |
            const fs = require('fs');
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('comments.json', 'utf-8'));
            const comments = jsonData.comments;
            for (const cmnt of comments) {
              comment_id = cmnt.id
              if (cmnt.author.login == 'author-name' || cmnt.body == 'foo') {
                github.rest.issues.deleteComment({
                  owner: context.repo.owner,
                  repo: context.repo.repo,
                  comment_id: comment_id,
                })
              }
            }
```

It is failing with:

```
 status: 404,
  response: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganization/MyRepo/issues/comments/IC_kwDODse5xs5r1sLf',
    status: 404,
.
.
.
```

Comment: Think about what the actual value of the script will be when it's had the values interpolated by the runner and gets executed... Why not just get it from the injected objects, rather than via string interpolation?

Comment: You don't _have_ to use JS. Learning the basics would be worthwhile if you're going to. Or compare your script more carefully to [the examples](https://github.com/actions/github-script#examples).

Comment: That said the problem's caused just _before_ the JS runs, in the YAML. Using `actions/github-script` is the worst of all worlds if you're not comfortable in JS because it makes it hard to test what you're running locally or in an automated way, let alone create the [mre] `const repopath = MyOrganization/MyRepository` (and unless you're using something like JetBrains' inject language don't even get syntax highlighting).

Comment: I have tried to change the approach per the example you suggested and now getting a new error (added in my question)